# Similar article by the same Google Author

Tags: seo, google-ranking, articles, google-authorship

I have two websites which are focusing on two different things (both are timbers, but different type of timber).

Let's say if I post in both sites an article (the article is about bush fire) which has exactly same content with exception of the last sentence, will one of the websites get penalized by Google for having duplicate content?

What if both sites use the same Google Author? Will this make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is duplicate content. Making a minor change does not make it unique content. Using the author markup will not make it acceptable. You should use canonical URLs on one of the pages. (If this article is the only duplicate content I wouldn't worry about it. BUt if you plan on doing this with a lot of content you will run into issues).

Comment: Do I have to use canonical URLs for both sites or just one of them?

Comment: Just one of them.